# Passing value to textbox with sql query via VBA code - MS ACCESS

Tags: vba

I am currently working in MS ACCESS. I have 2 forms one called **MyForm** and the second one name **Transit**. I have one table called **SimulationTable** which have 4 fields Fiscal_Year, Scenario_Number, Description and Operating_Unit. I would like with VBA code when clicking in a button to display result of SQL query in the textbox called **TXTBOX** which is in Transit form. I have tried many times but it doesn't work.
Any idea of how to fix ? Thank you.

Here is the SQL query:

```
SELECT SimulationTable.Description FROM SimulationTable WHERE Fiscal_Year=Forms!MainForm!OperatingFY AND Operating_Unit = Forms!MainForm!Text3 AND Scenario_Number = Forms!MainForm!Selected_scenario
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could just use DLookup():

```
Me.TXTBOX = DLookup("[Description]", "SimulationTable", "Fiscal_Year=" & Forms!MainForm!OperatingFY & _ 
    " AND Operating_Unit = " & Forms!MainForm!Text3 & _ 
    " AND Scenario_Number = " & Forms!MainForm!Selected_scenario)
```

Are these criteria fields all number type? Is TXTBOX bound to a field? If not, could even just put the DLookup() expression in ControlSource property.

Answer (score 0):

It works. I have added apostrophes around the "Operating_Unit" which is a field in text format. Thanks very much June7.

```
Me.TXTBOX = DLookup("[Description]", "SimulationTable", "Fiscal_Year=" & Forms!MainForm!OperatingFY & " AND Operating_Unit ='" & Forms!MainForm!Text3 & "' AND Scenario_Number =" & Forms!MainForm!Selected_scenario)
```